# Windows Server Docker containers - Which (if any) server roles can be replaced?

Tags: windows-server, docker-for-windows

G'day All,

NB: I am very new to Docker and well, Windows administration.

I was starting to explore Docker and found there were a whole bunch of Windows Server images.

Would you use/suggest/recommend ever using Docker in lieu of bare metal or VM in a non-dev environment?

ie, Would you get a suitably built machine, install Microsoft Server on it (or virtualize, whichever). Then install a bunch of Docker containers with persistent storage. ie

```
Windows Server 2019:
- Docker AD/DC
- Docker Print Server
- Docker File Server (with persistent storage)
- Docker Windows 10 machine(s).
```

Would this work? Or is my understanding way off?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into setting up a Windows AD/DC within a container, but it was a no-go.  Mainly because of persisting data across restarts, but also because of too many hoops to jump through.  Read this discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/ct77og/containerized_windows_domain/

and

https://serverfault.com/questions/872413/is-it-possible-to-add-active-directory-to-a-windows-container

It's not worth the struggle.  I just kept mine as a VM using very small resources with Server Core.